# Why should I await response.read(), but I don't need to await response.status?

Tags: python, asynchronous, post, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I don't understand how asynchronous requests work. Here I have a function that sends an image using a POST request:

```
async def post_img(in_url, in_filepath, in_filename):
with open(in_filepath, 'rb') as file:
    in_files = {'file': file}
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(in_url, data=in_files) as response:
            status = response.status
            response = await response.read()
            print(response)
```

Why I can read response status without awaiting it? How can I tell that request is done if I am not waiting for it to finish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why I can read response status without awaiting it?

Because you have already awaited it implicitly when you wrote `async with session.post(...)`. `async with session.post(...) as response` reads the response **header**, and exposes its data in the `response` object. The status code arrives the very beginning of the response and is available for any correct response.

You have to await the response **body** using `await response.read()` because the contents of the body is not part of the request object. Since the body can be of arbitrary size, reading it automatically might take too much time and exhaust available memory.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's still a little bit unclear. So when I wrote `async with session.post(...) as response` I already awaited it yes? If I already got the response why should I await body? Where is it if it's not in request object?

Comment: @MrLalatg When you wrote `async with session.post(...)` you already awaited the response **header**. You didn't await the response **body**. *Where is it if it's not in request object?* It's still on the server, with the initial packets probably being in the network or in your kernel buffers already. Imagine the body being 10 GiB large - you wouldn't want Python to try to download it automatically just so you wouldn't have to await `response.read()`!